# UICollectionViewCell Custom Segue ViewController Connection error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

at current i have the following code as shown below:

GroupsViewController.m

```
#import "GroupsViewController.h"
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface GroupsViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages;
    NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
    NSString * _titleForNextVC;
}

@end

@implementation GroupsViewController
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDelegate:self];
    reuseIdentifier= @"SmallIcon";

    arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A.png",@"B.png",@"C.png",nil];

    arrayOfDescriptions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell IconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[cell IconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _titleForNextVC = cell.IconLabel.text;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"]) {

        GroupsHomeViewController *vc = (GroupsHomeViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.titleText = _titleForNextVC;
    }
}

- (void)setTitleText:(NSString *)titleText {

    _titleText = _titleForNextVC;

    // Set Title of your ViewController
    self.title = _titleText;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Toggle View Button
- (IBAction)cellToggleAction:(id)sender {

    if([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SmallIcon"]){
        reuseIdentifier=@"ListView";
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LargeIcon"]];
    }
    else if
        ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListView"]){
        reuseIdentifier=@"LargeIcon";
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SmallIcon"]];
    }
    else if
        ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LargeIcon"]){
        reuseIdentifier=@"SmallIcon";
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListView"]];
    }

    [self.GroupsCollectionView reloadData];
}

//Toggled Cell Sizes
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize cellSize;

    if([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SmallIcon"])
        cellSize = CGSizeMake(100, 130);
    else if
        ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListView"])
        cellSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50);
    else if
        ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LargeIcon"])
        cellSize = CGSizeMake(320, 360);

    return cellSize;
}

@end
```

GroupsHomeViewController.m

```
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"

@interface GroupsHomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation GroupsHomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Well the problem seems to be that i cannot get to my new `ViewController` via my custom segue once i have clicked on one of my `UiCollectionViewcells`. Basically i click a cell in my `UICollectionView` and the title disappears but it does nothing else. It should open up `GroupsHomeViewController` and set the title of the View Controller to be the label that is placed within the cell i have just clicked. I can't even see if my current title will even work either as i can't get my`GroupsHomeViewController` to display.

I assume i am missing a line of code somewhere along the lines, but i am struggling to find out where or what it can be that due to receiving no error message's at all.

Also i would just like to point out that i am new to this and have only been developing my app in my spare time for the past month or so. So it would be greatly appreciated if you were to help me with this problem and i thank you in advance for any direction as to what i may be missing.

Comment: You'll get better answers if your question is *Minimal*, Complete and Verifiable (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is, give us the least amount of code required to reproduce your problem instead of giving us full classes.

Comment: How did you add the segue?

Comment: I controlled clicked from my GroupsViewController Orange/Yellow button at the top on my ViewController in Storyboard mode and dropped it down on to my Second Empty ViewController e.g. GroupsHomeViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is you need to save off "what ever" your trying to pass to the next view controller in a property. In your case i think you have in _titleForNextVC

next is you need to name your segue in your storyboard e.g "GroupsHomeSegue" then you can

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [self collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _titleForNextVC = cell.IconLabel.text;

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupsHomeSegue" sender:self];
}
```

then it would work

Comment: applying your suggested code actually gives me a reaction/error code now thank you i must be one step closer. The only problem now is i receive the following error upon selection of a cell. 2016-02-08 22:44:00.935 Octane Hub[553:10961] -[UITabBarController setTitleText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fefb3754ba0
2016-02-08 22:44:00.942 Octane Hub[553:10961] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setTitleText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fefb3754ba0'

Comment: can you mark my answer then? the remaining errors we can figure out if you post a different problem

Comment: do you have a UITabBarController in the destination viewController you are going to ?

Comment: Yes i have them all embedded in a tab bar controller and a view controller so that i can continuously keep my bottom and top bar

Comment: yea that is unrelated to this question if you comment out that code your error should go away